# JavaScript switch for changing background colour with css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, switch-statement, background-color

I have a very simple function which should change the page background colour based on specific links being clicked, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

Here is a demo of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/cF74Y/

It seems like it must be such a trivial mistake, but I can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your code here. Some people may not have access to Fiddle

Comment: Stop trying to rollback my changes, code should be part of the question.

Comment: @Jack I thought they were changes I made and forgot to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compare string with number, change `switch (currentItem)` to `switch (+currentItem)` will make your demo work.

***Addition:*** You could pass the `currentItem` as a parameter instead of using global variable.

***[Here is the working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/cF74Y/24/)***

Comment: Ah, that was it. I knew it would be something stupid. Thanks a lot. The variable is global because a few other functions use it.

Comment: you can again pass that variable as a parameter to `other functions` as well... As a rule of thumb try avoiding globals to the maximum extent...

Comment: @xdazz : Just one doubt... What difference oes that `+` sign make? Will it type cast the string to integer?

Comment: @Maverick Yes, it cast string to number.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're complicating things too much, can't you just do this?

**html:**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="color" href="#">red</a></li>
    <li><a class="color" href="#">green</a></li>
    <li><a class="color" href="#">blue</a></li>
    <li><a class="color" href="#">yellow</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a.color').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', $(this).text());
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/8yev9/

**Edit:** And if you need to assign a color by index use an array, I don't think you need that ugly `switch` statement, seems pretty useless to me, all that code can be reduced to just this:

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
$('a.color').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', colors[$(this).parent().index()]);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/8yev9/1

Comment: +1 for the array suggestion. Or an object could be used if for some reason the indexes were non-numeric or non-sequential.

Comment: Yes the array is a great suggestion. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Hi how can i make it work? I try copying the code from the sample you gave but it's not working. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var index = parseInt($(this).attr('id'),10);
```

then it will work.

Reason: the return type of .attr() function is a string and it  make true case 1 always. just use parseInt function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to give the parameter 'currentItem' with the function call.

```
changeBg(currentItem); // call
```

And your function will look like this:

```
function changeBg(currentItem) {
    var bg = 'null';
    switch (currentItem) {
        case 1 :
            bg = '#6A6A6A';
[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working copy

http://jsfiddle.net/cF74Y/34/

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInt` to compare with case.With this its unable to compare.See fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/cF74Y/43/